# Y axis in single stacked bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to display a single stacked bar chart representing atmospheric layers at various altitudes.

```
altitude = [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 35, 60, 100]
pd.DataFrame(altitude).T.plot(kind='bar',
                              stacked=True, color='lightgray',
                              edgecolor="black",
                              legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The y-axis seems messed up, how can I have linearly spaced ticks between `0` and `altitude[-1]`, ie 100km ?

Bonus question : I don't need the 0 on the x-axis, how can I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The y-axis is actually correct. What the stacked plot is doing is literally stacking up each of the values. The altitudes sum up to 231, so that's what the plot goes up to. What you seem to be looking for is a stacked plot with each of the height differences accounted for. This can be done using `np.diff` with `prepend=0` to account for the initial height being 0.

For the x-axis ticks, those can be removed using the `tick_params` method where you set `bottom=False` and `labelbottom=False`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.close("all")

altitudes = np.array([1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 35, 60, 100])
heights = np.diff(altitudes, prepend=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pd.DataFrame(heights).T.plot(kind="bar",
                             stacked=True, 
                             color="lightgray",
                             edgecolor="k",
                             legend=False,
                             ax=ax)
ax.tick_params(bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! As a side note it's possible to call `plt.xticks([])` instead of using `ax.tick_params()`